# Lambda Expression for join operation

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `SQL query` which I am performing on two tables.

Here is my query

```
Select a.cSubGroupName,a.cAddedBy,a.dAddedOn,b.cGroupName 
from sys_Log_Account_SubGroup a,sys_Account_Primary_Group b 
where a.cAuthorizedStatus='Pending'  and a.nGroupCode=b.nGroupCode
```

I am trying to perform the same query using `Lambda expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = tA
    .Where(a => a.cAuthorizedStatus == "Pending")
    .Join(tB, a => a.nGroupCode, b => b.nGroupCode, (a, b) => new 
    { 
        cSubGroupName = a.cSubGroupName, 
        cAddedBy = a.cAddedBy, 
        dAddedOn = a.dAddedOn, 
        cGroupName = b.cGroupName 
    });
```

or

```
var query = tA
    .Join(tB, a => a.nGroupCode, b => b.nGroupCode, (a, b) => new 
    { 
        cSubGroupName = a.cSubGroupName, 
        cAddedBy = a.cAddedBy, 
        dAddedOn = a.dAddedOn, 
        cGroupName = b.cGroupName,
        cAuthorizedStatus = a.cAuthorizedStatus
    })
    .Where(j => j.cAuthorizedStatus == "Pending")
    .Select(j => new
    { 
        cSubGroupName = j.cSubGroupName, 
        cAddedBy = j.cAddedBy, 
        dAddedOn = j.dAddedOn, 
        cGroupName = j.cGroupName
    });
```

Note that the last select is only necessary if you want to explicity exclude the `cAuthorizedStatus` column in the return set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trying to understand the expression ,thanks.

Comment: @freebird. The .Join method takes: 1. set to (inner) join on 2. key to join left set on 3. key to join right set on 4. output set (column list).